# ¿Cómo encontrar la ruta para agregar a la RUTA después de instalar un software?

Tags: unix, rutas

Intento instalar software, [minishift](https://github.com/minishift/minishift), y en un momento me piden que extraiga la ruta, pero no sé cómo encontrarla.

En la [página de ayuda con la instalación](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/installing.html), me pide :

1. Descargar el archivo de su sistema operativo desde la [página de Versiones de Minishift](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/installing.html) y extraiga su contenido.
2. Agregar el minishift binario a su RUTA Pero no encontré el camino cuando estaba buscando con `$ PATH=$PATH:~`

Por lo momento hizo :

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/home/mike/minishift-1.19.0-linux-amd64/
$ export PATH
```

Pero luego tengo que hacerlo cada vez que abro mi consola

Comment: Es allí donde has extraído el contenido.

Comment: _Pero luego tengo que hacerlo cada vez que abro mi consola_. Claro, pues este valor se define al hacer login. Debes añadir `PATH=$PATH:/home/mike/minishift-1.19.0-linux-amd64/` en `~/.bashrc`, que es el fichero que se carga cuando haces login.

Comment: @fedorqui Ha ? Y como anadirlo a `./bashrc`entonces ?

Comment: Abriéndolo, añadiendo la línea y guardándolo.